# Как сделать такую анимацию волны?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Как сделать такую анимацию волны, как в примере? По коду не могу понять толком, что тут происходит. Может кто-нибудь знает какой-нибудь урок, где подробно разбирают создание такой анимации?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var waves = ["rgba(7, 62, 149, 1)",
             "rgba(7, 62, 149, 0.7)"]
var i = 0;
function draw() {
  canvas.width = canvas.width;
  for(var j = waves.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    var offset = i + j * Math.PI * 12;
    ctx.fillStyle = (waves[j]);
    var randomLeft            = (Math.sin(offset/100)  + 1)       / 2 * 200;
    var randomRight           = (Math.sin((offset/100) + 10) + 1) / 2 * 200;
    var randomLeftConstraint  = (Math.sin((offset/60)  + 2)  + 1) / 2 * 200;
    var randomRightConstraint = (Math.sin((offset/60)  + 1)  + 1) / 2 * 200;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, randomLeft + 100);
    // ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, randomRight + 100);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(canvas.width / 3, randomLeftConstraint, canvas.width / 3 * 2, randomRightConstraint, canvas.width, randomRight + 100);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width , canvas.height);
    ctx.lineTo(0, canvas.height);
    ctx.lineTo(0, randomLeft + 100);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
  i = i + 3;
}
setInterval("draw()", 20);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#canvas {
  background-color:#FAFAFA;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: что конкретно в примере Вам не понятно? тут используется 2 кривые безье, точки для которых получаются при помощи синуса от номера кадра с какими то коэфициентами.